# Me gustaria crear un nuevo array con .map con la condicion de que si la fecha actual es menor que la fecha del objeto creado, se añada a dicho array

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, objeto

https://codepen.io/jdluis/pen/bGaOdMv

Buenas, como digo en el título me gustaría poder añadir este tipo de función a mi proyecto, he creado un codePen con la idea de lo que quiero hacer, ya que mi proyecto es más grande y sería muy lioso comprobarlo en él. Básicamente, tengo un array donde guardo unos objetos, dicho objeto tiene la propiedad Date, la cual es la fecha del evento producido. Pues quiero que los eventos que ya hayan superado la fecha actual no aparezcan en la sección de eventos que estoy generando en mi proyecto, es por ello que necesito comparar de alguna manera para que me origine el nuevo array, se me ocurrió .map pero no se como lo podría hacer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función que buscas es `filter()`, la cual crea un nuevo array con los elementos que cumplan la condición que especifiques:

```
let actualEvents = events.filter((event) => {
  return ActualFullDate() > event.date;
});
```

Aquí tienes la documentación de la función: [Array.prototype.filter() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Muchas gracias Eric

Comment: @jdluis.com Un placer! Si puedes marca la respuesta como aceptada porfa 

Comment: Hecho, disculpa.